# How to print C# console writeline?

Tags: c#, .net

I am Python developer, zero knowledge of C#, trying to run a prediction from a Python model in C#. Output comes as an array, not sure how to print the array of values on the console.

Python output:

```
[array([1.], dtype=int64), array([[0.04024667, 0.95975333]], dtype=float32)]
```

Results have the outputs, it has [0] and [1.], where [0] has the highest out of the two array values "{1}" and [1.] has the array values "{{0.04024667,0.9597533}}" . Shown in the picture.

[image]

How should I print the array values in console, I expect the array values come out as in console as below

```
0.04024667
0.9597533
```

If I can get the along with Value in [0], that will be good as well, like

```
1
0.04024667
0.9597533
```

My code to print the output not working

```
using (var results = Session.Run(outputs))
{
    foreach (var r in results)
    {
        var prediction = r.AsTensor<float>().GetArrayString();
        Console.WriteLine(prediction);
    }
}
```

Comment: `string.Join(",",prediction)` or maybe `string.Join(",",results.Select(r => [some expression to turn the result into a string] ))`

Comment: That's not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a way

```
            using (var results = Session.Run(outputs))
            {
                var highestIndex = results.First().AsTensor<long>().First();
                Console.WriteLine(highestIndex);

                var values = results.Last().AsTensor<float>();
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }
            }
```

got the output
[image]